# Javascript Xml Count

Tags: javascript, xml, nodes

Sample XML.

```
<node>
<nodeid>28</nodeid>
<account_no xsi:nil="true" />
<address1>15 CANCUN CT</address1>
<serial_no>112199543</serial_no>
<x_lat>25.95513358000</x_lat>
<y_lon>-97.49027147000</y_lon>
<alarm>
  <alarmid>Outage</alarmid>
  <alarmtime>2012-07-30T14:46:29</alarmtime>
</alarm>
<alarm>
  <alarmid>Restore</alarmid>
  <alarmtime>2012-07-30T14:55:29</alarmtime>
</alarm>
</node>
<node>
<nodeid>67</nodeid>
<account_no>274192</account_no>
<address1>1618 CHIPINQUE DR</address1>
<serial_no>112199521</serial_no>
<x_lat>25.95286395000</x_lat>
<y_lon>-97.49323166000</y_lon>
<alarm>
  <alarmid>Outage</alarmid>
  <alarmtime>2012-07-30T14:46:29</alarmtime>
</alarm>
</node>
</ROOT>
```

I want to count the number of

```
<alarm>
```

elements the first node has as well as the second.  I tried to do this in a for loop...

```
xmlDoc.getElementByTagName('alarm')[i].length;
```

this gives me all number of 'alarm' tags in the xml file.  Which all i want is the current 'node' alarm elements.  So here is what I want, I want for it to tell me the first  has 2

```
<alarm>
```

tags and the second 'node' has 1

```
<alarm>
```

Just javascript no jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('node'), //Get the <node> tags
    amountOfNodes = nodes.length

for(var i = 0; i < amountOfNodes; i++) { //loop thru the nodes

   console.log(nodes[i].getElementsByTagName('alarm').length); //get the amount of <alarm> tags

}
```

**EDIT**
Here's a working example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncvuq/).

Tell me if that solves your problem :)

Comment: Thanks the nodes[i].getElementsByTagName('alarm').length was what i needed.  Thank you!